# Is there any plugin available to migrate from 1.2.3 to 2.0.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am migrating rails application from 1.2.3 to 2.0.2. Can anyone tell me if there is any plugin available for this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Holy old versions, Batman!!1!ONE! (and I'm sorry I can't help you...)

Comment: Owwww man. My deepest and sincerest sympathy. Why not upgrade to something a bit more recent while you are at it?

Answer (score 1):

I recently took a 1.0 app all the way to 3.0 by going through 1.2, 2.0, 2.3, then 3. There are no plugins that I know of, but there are certainly plenty of guides.

From the [release announcement](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2007/12/7/rails-2-0-it-s-done):

> If you want to move your application to Rails 2.0, you should first move it to Rails 1.2.6. That’ll include deprecation warnings for most everything we yanked out in 2.0. So if your application runs fine on 1.2.6 with no deprecation warnings, there’s a good chance that it’ll run straight up on 2.0. Of course, if you’re using, say, pagination, you’ll need to install the classic_pagination plugin. If you’re using Oracle, you’ll need to install the activerecord-oracle-adapter gem. And so on and so forth for all the extractions.

There are plenty of blog posts around, [Peter Marklunds](http://marklunds.com/articles/one/409) is particularily good.

One thing I did before anything else was to start managing the dependencies with Bundler. I [blogged about this at the time](http://douglasfshearer.com/blog/using-bundler-with-rails-12), was definitely useful.

Comment: Actually i too have to have to upgrade my application from rails 1.2.3 to 2.0,2.3.12,3.0.9..can u just suggest me which guide do i need to refer.

Comment: Each time I upgraded I ran `rails app` from the parent directory of the app, as if I was overwriting it. I would carefully work my way through each file it finds a conflict with, copying any important stuff out, letting it overwrite the file, then pasting the important stuff back in. This works really well, especially if you have good test coverage. Most problems will appear as deprecation warnings before they are actually a problem.